# c# executed even when in false loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

I am trying to use a basic if else case, but the if is executed no matter what.

This is the code found in the backend, on the aspx.cs file.

```
if (1==2)
            {
                // 22/09/2014 12:00:00 AM for en
                //format date for submit
                Dateformatted = this.DateField.Value.ToString();
                DateSplit = Dateformatted.Split('/');
                yearAt0 = DateSplit[2].Split(' ');
                Datetosubmit = yearAt0[0] + "/" + DateSplit[1] + "/" + DateSplit[0] + " 00:00:00";
            }
            else
            {
                // 2014-09-22 00:00:00 for fra
                //format date for submit
                Dateformatted = this.DateField.Value.ToString();
                DateSplit = Dateformatted.Split('-');
                dayAt0 = DateSplit[2].Split(' ');
                Datetosubmit = DateSplit[0] + "/" + DateSplit[1] + "/" + dayAt0[0] + " 00:00:00";
            }
```

This is the error I get (line 1209 is red):

```
   System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   Line 1207:                string Dateformatted = this.DateFieldEdit.Value.ToString();
   Line 1208:                string[] DateSplit = Dateformatted.Split('/');
Line 1209:                string[] yearAt0 = DateSplit[2].Split(' ');
   Line 1210:                string Datetosubmit = yearAt0[0] + "/" + DateSplit[1] + "/" +     DateSplit[0] + " 00:00:00";
   Line 1211:
```

This clearly indicates that the code inside the false part of the if statement was executed. Is there a reason for this? How can I fix this?

Note: The if (1==2) was added to simplify the example, it is normally a parameter

Comment: Could your PDB and binary be out of synch?

Comment: if false will always return true.  What are you trying to check for a boolean value.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError possibly, do you know how I could check this?

Comment: @Sorceri exactly, I am trying to force the else part of the statement to execute

Comment: @Steve based on the error, you can see that  `DateSplit = Dateformatted.Split('/');` was executed and not `DateSplit = Dateformatted.Split('-');`, meaning that the false part was executed

Comment: @Sorceri even if i use `if(1==2)` I still get the same result

Comment: _Note: The if (false) was added to simplify the example, it is normally a parameter._ The problem should most definitely be associated with that parameter.

Comment: you should fix your example as it is misleading to put if(false) whith your question asked.

Comment: @Sorceri if(false) will never return true! Where did you get that idea?

Comment: I worded it wrong, meaning it would go to the else clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see this effect if your binaries and your PDB files are out of sync.  If you are using the updated PDBs, but the old binaries, that would definitely explain this scenario.

The easiest way to fix this to to completely clean and rebuild everything.  Deleting everything in your `bin` and `obj` folders for good measure.  You should also restart the IIS instance you are using.